# Specific Label Value From GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to delete rows from `ASP.NET GridView` and for demo purpose, I am trying to retrieve names from the rows right now. In the `ItemTemplate` of the `GridView`, I've included `Label` that has id as well name to show. Finally added `Button` control in the `GridView` to delete specific rows and tried the following:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductId") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
              <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnShow" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnShow_Click" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

In the code-behind, I've iterated the `GridView` with a loop to get the individual values, say name of the row as follows:

```
protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    foreach (GridViewRow row in grdData.Rows)
    {
        string val = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblName")).Text;

        lblMsg.Text = val;
    }
}
```

But unfortunately I get the last name every time I click any row button and here is the screen-shot that I am trying:

[image: ASP.NET GridView]

Whenever I click any button, it shows the last name **Ice-Cream** every time. Anything that I missed here?

Comment: Of course you will get the last name as inside the loop your value of `val` and `lblMsg.Text` keep getting overwritten and what you will end up with is the value from the last row in the iteration.

Comment: I would suggest you to assign some `Commandname` to your button 'btnShow' and then handle the `GridView` `RowCommand` event. or if its the only button in your Gridview just assign it the command name `select` and handle it the code inside the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductId") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnShow" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnShow_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server"></asp:Label>

    protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        lblMsg.Text = (sender as Button).CommandArgument;
    }
```